# Best way to implement thread safe atomic accessors of a long property on a guaranteed 64 bit architecture without lock

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a property its type is long (Int64).

If it would be an int, then I could declare the backing field as:

```
private volatile int _myInt;
```

and create a simple get and set accessor.

However the C# compiler does not allow using the volatile keyword with the type long, even with the x64 project settings. So the situation is that even we are sure that the read/write operations are atomic on this variable, unfortunately there is a danger that a thread which reads the variable will get and use a way old (processor or CLR/JIT optimizer) cached value...

Question1: Is this means that instead of simply reading this value in the get accessor I have to use Interlocked to prevent reading a cached value?

```
get
{
    return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _myLong, 0, 0);
}
```

This means a quite overhead...

Question2: Still supposing a guaranteed 64 bit architecture, Is it enough a simple assignment in the set accessor like:

```
set
{
    _myLong = value;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: A lot of famous C# luminaries have spoken on such issues in the past, and I dare not put any words of my own into their mouths (and hence sorry, no summary provided.) Please visit these luminaries blog posts and enjoy. [Link to Eric Lippert posted 2011/06/16](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx), etc. I'll let others to add links to other blog posts.

Comment: @rwong: I've read carefully the link you provided. Although it is all clear, and all correct as far as I can decide, it says nothing new about the problem I exposed. Also, my question was an implementation question, regarding performance and correctness and not theoretical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [System.Threading.Volatile class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.volatile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to solve this problem.  For example:

```
class Example {
    private long _prop;
    public long prop {
        get { return Volatile.Read(ref _prop); }
        set { Volatile.Write(ref _prop, value); }
    }
}
```

While this *looks* inefficient it in fact generates highly efficient code on a x64 processor.  The jitter has built-in knowledge of the Volatile class and directly translates it to machine code instead of relying on the framework implementation.  And the x64 jitter knows that *long* is atomic on a 64-bit Intel/AMD processor.  For example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var obj = new Example();
        obj.prop = 42;
        Console.WriteLine(obj.prop);
    }
```

Generates this machine code:

```
00007FFA3DF43AB0  sub         rsp,28h                     ; setup stack frame
00007FFA3DF43AB4  lea         rcx,[7FFA3DF959B0h]         ; obj = new Example
00007FFA3DF43ABB  call        00007FFA9D5A2300  
00007FFA3DF43AC0  mov         qword ptr [rax+8],2Ah       ; obj.prop setter
00007FFA3DF43AC8  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rax+8]       ; obj.prop getter
00007FFA3DF43ACC  call        00007FFA9CD0CFD0            ; Console.WriteLine
00007FFA3DF43AD1  nop                                     ; alignment
00007FFA3DF43AD2  add         rsp,28h                     ; destroy stack frame
00007FFA3DF43AD6  ret                                     ; done
```

And note how the property getter and setter were completely eliminated, accessing the Example._prop field directly.  Which is what you were looking for.  If you ever run this code on a processor with a weak memory model, like ARM, then it will still work correctly with the appropriate acquire and release semantics getting generated, as required by such a processor.

Comment: Thx for the details. It is surely my missing knowledge, could you explain how the read access to the memory location ( mov         rcx,qword ptr ...) ensures reading the most recent value, I mean how it is invalidates the processor data cache?

Comment: Hmya, that's not what you asked for.  Trivially use the *lock* statement that get that guarantee.

Comment: What I really do not understand seeing this machine code, where are the fences?. Should not the final code result in the same semantics  as volatile keyword does? (I mean Volatile.Read() and Volatile.Write())

Comment: It does.  Read the part at the bottom, "If you ever run this code on a processor with a weak memory model".  x64 is not weak.  Try looking at the machine code when you use *volatile* explicitly.