# VB.NET: Do I need to call Thread.MemoryBarrier() before each read if I always complete my writes with Thread.MemoryBarrier()?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety, memory-model

VB.Net does not have an equivalent of C# volatile keyword so you have to manually implement volatile which is usually done by calling Thread.MemoryBarrier() before read and after write. So something like this is equivalent to declaring C# volatile variable:

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets a value indicating whether this instance is disposed.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property IsDisposed As Boolean
        Get
            Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier()
            Return _isDisposed
        End Get
        Private Set(value As Boolean)
            _isDisposed = value
            Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier()
        End Set
    End Property
```

I am wondering of the memory barrier before read is necessary if the only place where I write to the variable is through a setter and there I always call Thread.MemoryBarrier() after the write.

Can I safely remove the Thread.MemoryBarrier() before read?

Edit: To make it more clear I am asking if I can remove the Thread.MemoryBarrier() before read in order to remove costs of memory fence for each read.

Comment: The [`Volatile` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.volatile(v=vs.110).aspx) should work in VB.net and the `Thread` class contains methods like [`VolatileRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdxzk5cw.aspx)

Comment: The question is can I safely remove the Thread.MemoryBarrier() before read to avoid potentially unnecessary cost of memory fence on reads.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can get stale reads if you remove it.

Comment: You can't remove it.  Pretty unlikely you are using it correctly when you ask this question btw.  [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27469253/17034).

Comment: Well the internet is a bit conflicting here then. Please look at: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx (excerpt: The static VolatileRead and VolatileWrite methods in the Thread class read/write a variable while enforcing (technically, a superset of) the guarantees made by the volatile keyword. Their implementations are relatively inefficient, though, in that they actually generate full fences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove the barrier on the read-side which is easy to show by example. Let's use this reader:

```
while (!IsDisposed); //reads _isDisposed
```

The value of `_isDisposed` can clearly be cached in a register here so that new writes will never become visible. This loop could be infinite (for example - other effects are possible such as long delays).

More formally, the reads of `_isDisposed` can all move "upwards" in time to appear to run before the store happens. `volatile` stores effect a release fence meaning that nothing can move over them later in time. Things can move over them to previous points in time, though.

Use the `Volatile` class. Or, use a struct written in C# as a wrapper around the field:

```
struct VolatileInt32Box { public volatile int Value; }
```

Comment: I will use the VolatileRead/VolatileWrite solution as proposed by Hans Passant.

Comment: @dcarapic for some reason those two methods are much slower. They compile to method calls. They have only disadvantages.

Comment: Not according to Hans pasant (link that he provided http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468923/best-way-to-implement-thread-safe-atomic-accessors-of-a-long-property-on-a-guara/27469253#27469253). Now I have not tested this but I have read from other sources that C# volatile keyword and VolatileWrite/VolatileRead should be similar in functionality and speed.

Comment: I have tested this a few days ago on the current 4.5 JIT and the next gen RyuJIT. RyuJIT generates good code, the current JIT continues to disappoint. Disregarding performance I recommend: Use the newer functionality (the Volatile class).